# In MicroPython: How to identify which instance of a library class is passed?

Tags: python, instance, micropython

How can I identify which instance of a library class has been passed to my interrupt routine?
I can create the instance with a unique id, and that unique id is shown if I print the instance, but how can I access that id when the instance is passed into my interrupt routine (which is only allowed one argument - the class instance).

```
>>> from machine import Pin
>>> switch = Pin(2, Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_UP)
>>> switch
Pin(2, mode=IN, pull=PULL_UP)
>>>
```

It's the first argument, the '2', which I require to access in my interrupt routine.
Obviously, being a library class, I have no access to the internals.

Comment: Does[ `isinstance(obj, type)`[(https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) help you?

Comment: @mhawke - I don't think so.  It can tell me that switch is an instance of Pin (which I already know), but I don't see how it can help me find the instance id.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like a `Pin` object exposes the pin number. The easiest solution is to just keep track of it yourself. You haven't shown us your code, so it's hard to make a concrete suggestion, but instead of just storing the `Pin` object, store the `Pin` object and an integer...

```
switch = (2, Pin(2, Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_UP))
```

Now the pin number is `switch[0]` and the `Pin` object itself is `switch[1]`. Or make a `Switch` class that encapsulates both, as well as whatever debounce logic you're using. Etc.

---

Alternately, you could patch MicroPython to expose the pin value. For the `esp8266` port (which is all I'm equipped to test at the moment), the necessary changes are minimal (this diff is against revision `680ce4532`):

```
diff --git a/ports/esp8266/machine_pin.c b/ports/esp8266/machine_pin.c
index 419ee87a7..b3830fe56 100644
--- a/ports/esp8266/machine_pin.c
+++ b/ports/esp8266/machine_pin.c
@@ -354,6 +354,13 @@ STATIC mp_obj_t pyb_pin_value(size_t n_args, const mp_obj_t *args) {
 }
 STATIC MP_DEFINE_CONST_FUN_OBJ_VAR_BETWEEN(pyb_pin_value_obj, 1, 2, pyb_pin_value);
 
+// pin.pin()
+STATIC mp_obj_t pyb_pin_pin(mp_obj_t self_in) {
+    pyb_pin_obj_t *self = self_in;
+    return MP_OBJ_NEW_SMALL_INT(self->phys_port);
+}
+STATIC MP_DEFINE_CONST_FUN_OBJ_1(pyb_pin_pin_obj, pyb_pin_pin);
+
 STATIC mp_obj_t pyb_pin_off(mp_obj_t self_in) {
     pyb_pin_obj_t *self = self_in;
     pin_set(self->phys_port, 0);
@@ -428,6 +435,7 @@ STATIC const mp_rom_map_elem_t pyb_pin_locals_dict_table[] = {
     // instance methods
     { MP_ROM_QSTR(MP_QSTR_init),    MP_ROM_PTR(&pyb_pin_init_obj) },
     { MP_ROM_QSTR(MP_QSTR_value),   MP_ROM_PTR(&pyb_pin_value_obj) },
+    { MP_ROM_QSTR(MP_QSTR_pin),     MP_ROM_PTR(&pyb_pin_pin_obj) },
     { MP_ROM_QSTR(MP_QSTR_off),     MP_ROM_PTR(&pyb_pin_off_obj) },
     { MP_ROM_QSTR(MP_QSTR_on),      MP_ROM_PTR(&pyb_pin_on_obj) },
     { MP_ROM_QSTR(MP_QSTR_irq),     MP_ROM_PTR(&pyb_pin_irq_obj) },
```

With this change in place, `Pin` objects have a new `pin()` method that returns the pin number:

```
>>> p = machine.Pin(2)
>>> p.pin()
2
```

I've submitted the above change [in a pull request](https://github.com/micropython/micropython/pull/7005), although I don't expect it to get accepted (because the change applies to a single port and it seems as if it ought to be more general).

Answer (score 0):

@larsks
I'm not sure that your first solution helps.  When the interrupt occurs, I need to know which IO pin triggered the interrupt.

When the irq is set up, the argument to specify to the handler is constrained to "take exactly one argument which is the Pin instance.", thus:

```
switch.irq(lambda pin:irq_handler(pin)).
```

If your second solution could be adopted/adapted to be universally applicable, it would be great.  Thank you for doing the work on that! I'm a little hesitant to start using a modified build (I only started work on micropython yesterday, when I received my first Raspberry Pico).

In the meantime, I have derived a solution, but it's a little long-winded, and not ideal for interrupt processing, although it could probably all be done in a scheduled call-back.

Anyway, any improvement on this:

```
from machine import Pin
import io

def get_id(*args, **kwargs):
    output = io.StringIO()
    print(*args, file=output, **kwargs)
    s = output.getvalue()
    output.close()
    myid=int(s[s.find('(')+1:s.find(',')])
    return myid

switch = Pin(25, Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_UP)
switch2 = Pin(13, Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_UP)
switchId=get_id(switch)
print (type(switchId), switchId)
switchId=get_id(switch2)
print (type(switchId), switchId)
```